# Serving static files with nginx

Tags: nginx, google-compute-engine, fileserver

I'm trying to serve static files(HTMLs, JS and CSS) from a Google compute engine instance running Debian 8.
I used git to clone the web app to the folder `/var/www/prod/app` with command

```
sudo git clone <my repo>
```

I made a conf file in sites-enabled folder `app.conf`. Here's the content

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/prod/app;
    location / {
    }
}
```

Isn't this config enough to make my machine serve the files when I type my machine's ip address/path in the browser?

I see the `welcome to nginx` page when I type my instance's ip address in browser. But none of the files in prod/app are served. I get 404 for all the paths I try.  Could someone help me configure this.

Comment: Can you check [what permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9402/what-file-permissions-should-i-set-on-web-root) do you have for the files you want to serve?

Comment: I figured it out. The `default` config in sites-enabled forlder had a server block that would override my config. Commented it out and things are working as expected.